# How do pass parameter datasrc DataTables Jquery?

Tags: web-services, stored-procedures, parameters, datatables

I have a small question as follow: I have a function that it takes on values input and returns JSON string. In my function GET_PRODUCT input a parameter as string @product_name . The result as JSON , I do not know how to pass parameters in here . I must declare how do use dataSrc in here (suppose webmethod GET_PRODUCT is work with parameter input )

```
var table;
            table = $('#div_table').DataTable({
            "processing": false,
            "serverSide": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../BUS/WebService.asmx/GET_PRODUCT",
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "POST",
                dataSrc: function (json) {
               //dataSrc: function (json(Candy)) {
                 //transfer parameter in here 
                 //result as JSON string will parsed and fill in DataTables
                    return $.parseJSON(json.d);
                },
                //dataSrc: "Candy",
            },
```

I do not understand the issue pass parameters in here. Please share with me.
Thank guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it work follow

```
 "ajax": {
                "url": "../BUS/WebService.asmx/GET_PRODUCT",
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "POST",
                data: function (data) { return "{'product_name':'Candy'}"; },
                dataSrc: function (json) { return $.parseJSON(json.d); }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the default data being send to the server by using the data parameter e.g.

```
  "data": function ( d ) {
    return $.extend( {}, d, {
    "product_name": "Candy"
  } );
```

The dataSrc parameter lets you manipulate the data that was being returned from the server. This can either be a string definining the property from the object being returned or a function which will have a single parameter, the JSON returned from the server.

```
  "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
    for ( var i=0, ien=json.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
      // manipulate the returned data in here!
    }
    return json;
  }
```

You can find more information on the ajax DataTable settings [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax).

Good luck.